# Changing equation to x equals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im currently stuck on this equation I need to modify to be in terms of x

$$y=-x^2+4$$

I got something like this which looks wrong

$$x = -\sqrt{y+4}$$

First you would subtract the 4 from both sides. Do you then divide by -1 then square root it?

Comment: Solve according to SAMDEB. Solving an equation is the unraveling of an evaluation, so you need to reverse the steps that you would normally use to evaluate an expression. If I gave you instructions on how to get to Wal-Mart, could you find your way back home again? It's the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

You should divide by $-1$ and then square root it. In the original equation, it is $y = -(x^2) + 4$. Doing this should get you $x = \sqrt{4-y}$.

Comment: Don't forget the $\pm$

Comment: oh okay thank you very much thats what I was thinking but wasnt sure

Comment: should it be $$\pm \sqrt{4-y}$$ ?

Comment: @MD_90, yeah it should have a $\pm$ as [abiessu](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/86846/abiessu) pointed out. I've always thought that the $\pm$ is implied by the radical sign.

Comment: im applying this to a calculus 2 problem so that is gonna be strange working with in a integral for area between two curves that has plus and minus square root

Answer (score 2):

Original equation, $y=-(x^2)+4$;
Minus $4$ from both sides, $y-4=-x^2;$
Multiply $(-1)$ to both sides, $x^2=-(y-4)$;
That gives you, $x^2=4-y$;
Square root it, $x=\pm\sqrt {4-y}$
Final ans is $x=\pm\sqrt {4-y}$.

Comment: Good algebra.  Do you have anything to add that hasn't been stated in the other answer?

Comment: I forgot to put the ± sign after square rooting. Thank you very much.